# Logstash - Calculate duration with ruby code

Tags: ruby, logstash

After several attempts to work with the "elapsed" filter to calculate the duration between events, I try to do so using Ruby code.
I can't quite figure out how I can get the time of a particular event based on its tag.

For example, these are my events:

05-07 13:20:48.808 1222 1236 D ShutdownThread: shutdown reason is: userrequested

05-07 10:22:28.306 657 657 I boot_progress_start: 9977

05-06 13:20:48.808 1222 1236 D ShutdownThread: shutdown reason is: userrequested

05-06 10:22:28.306 657 657 I boot_progress_start: 9977

05-05 13:20:48.808 1222 1236 D ShutdownThread: shutdown reason is: userrequested

05-05 10:22:28.306 657 657 I boot_progress_start: 9977

This is my code for now:

```
filter {
    dissect {
    mapping => {
    "message" => "%{[@metadata][timestamp]} %{+[@metadata][timestamp]} %{} %{} %{loglevel} %{msg}"
        }
    }   
date{
    match => [ "[@metadata][timestamp]", "MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS" ]
}

#device ON
if "boot_progress_start" in [message] {
    mutate {
        add_tag => "ON_event" 
    }
}

#device OFF
else if "shutdown reason is: userrequested" in [message] {
    mutate {
        add_tag => "OFF_event" 
    }
}
```

How my code in Ruby is supposed be if I want to calculate the time between "ON" and "OFF" events.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In Logstash the events are independent from each other, your `OFF` event wouldn't have any information about your `ON` event, to calculate the duration between two events you would need a common value present in both, for example an unique id for each pair of events.

To do that using the ruby filter you would need to store the time of the `ON` event somewhere and query it for each `OFF` event that arrives in your logstash, you could store it in elasticsearch or another database that has a filter in pipeline.

The easiest way to do that is using the elapsed filter, in both cases you would need to set your pipeline to use only 1 worker, depending on the time difference between your events, this would be the only way to make sure that your `OFF` event would not go through your pipeline before your `ON` event.

Comment: Thank you! using java-execution=false and pipeline.workers=1 elapsed filter as you suggest helped me to get the wanted result.